# How to use Pattern matching to get the right hand side of a rule?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, rule

I have a List that looks as follows:

```
{{"DQLQGILASERKMNN"} -> -1, {"GSSHHHHHHSSGLVP"} -> -1, {"LTKAEETKEIITMGR"} -> -1, {"LEKSMAELTQLFNDM"} -> 1, {"YRSCVDEYESAIGNL"} -> 1}
```

I would like to apply pattern matching in order to get a list containing only the r.h.s of the rules as follows:

```
{-1, -1, -1, 1, 1}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `rules[[All,2]]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{{"DQLQGILASERKMNN"} -> -1, {"GSSHHHHHHSSGLVP"} -> -1, {"LTKAEETKEIITMGR"} -> -1, {"LEKSMAELTQLFNDM"} ->  1, {"YRSCVDEYESAIGNL"} -> 1}
    /. (x_ -> y_) -> y
```

This works, using purely pattern matching.

Alternatively:

```
list = {{"DQLQGILASERKMNN"} -> -1, {"GSSHHHHHHSSGLVP"} -> -1, {"LTKAEETKEIITMGR"} -> -1, {"LEKSMAELTQLFNDM"} -> 1, {"YRSCVDEYESAIGNL"} -> 1};

Last /@ list
```

Or, courtesy of J.M.'s comment:

```
Values[list]
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Values[list]` also works.